# how to keep text box and button in the same line in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to keep text box and button in the same line, but it's coming in two different lines:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <div>
<div style="float:left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditExpenses(0)">Add Expense</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ReportExpense()">Expense Report</button>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:40%;">
    <form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Index" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-info">Filter</button>
        </div>
       
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add them a css class with display: inline-block property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your parent element, containing the input and button element a flex box. I used the bootstrap utility classes to achieve this. I added a small margin to the input element as well, also using a bootstrap utility class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditExpenses(0)">Add Expense</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ReportExpense()">Expense Report</button>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; width:40%;">
    <form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Index" class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex">
        <input class="form-control mr-1" type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-info">Filter</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to achieve exactly what you want is something like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditExpenses(0)">Add Expense</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ReportExpense()">Expense Report</button>
    </div>

    <form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Index" class="form-group col-sm-4 d-flex">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-info">Filter</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Filter" button goes in the second line since Bootstrap's `form-control` class has `display: block` and `width: 100%`. Change [`display: inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) and reduce `width: 50%`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditExpenses(0)">Add Expense</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ReportExpense()">Expense Report</button>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; width:40%;">
    <form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Index" class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-info">Filter</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
   <div style="float:left">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEditExpenses(0)">Add Expense</button>
     <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ReportExpense()">Expense Report</button>
   </div>
   <div style="float:right; width:40%;">
     <form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Index" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
           <div class="d-flex">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-info ml-2">Filter</button>
           </div>
         </div>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```